# how to write a pl/sql code block that prints out contents of cursor that is out parameter from stored proc

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-01858

I have a stored procedure that takes in two dates and passes back a cursor. The stored procedure compiles however I am having trouble writing the correct pl/sql to 'see' what is returned.  I have tried the following:

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MY_CURSOR=' || MY_CURSOR)

declaring local variables that represent the columns contained in a row  of the cursor
then I

loop
fetch MY_CURSOR into the local variables
exit when MY_CURSOR%notfound
DBMS_OUTPUT_PUTLINE(local variable 1 || local variable 2 etc..)
end loop
close MY_CURSOR

The loop seems to execute further however I get an error on my fetchline:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at line 18

Can anyone provide any advice?

Comment: It would help if you could include real code and some sample data.  What, exactly, is on line 18?

Answer (score 1):

The loop works for my needs - I had the variables in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

> The loop seems to execute further however I get an error on my fetchline: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected ORA-06512: at line 18

Check the types of the local variables you are fetching into.

Seems you try to fetch a `VARCHAR2` field into a `NUMBER` variable.